# Why Amazon SES bounce events are flowing to multiple SNS endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I have 2 different web apps using the same Amazon SES account and Key and Secret.

The first web app controls automated marketing flows based on subscriber behaviors.

The second is for one-off email campaigns (bulk emails to the entire list of subscribers).

I have one SNS Topic created at https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/v3/home?region=us-east-1#/topics for each of those web apps. (This is for open and click tracking.)

I have one SNS Subscription (HTTPS) created at https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/v3/home?region=us-east-1#/subscriptions for each of those web apps. Each is subscribed to the appropriate SNS Topic.

The first app also uses a [Configuration Set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-custom-open-click-domains.html#configure-custom-open-click-domain-config-set) to ensure that its mail events use the proper SNS Topic.

However, "bounce" events for emails sent from the first web app have been somehow flowing to *both* SNS Topics.

The HTTPS endpoint of the second web app therefore receives information that it doesn't expect and then complains because it can't find the message_id because it was not the web app who originally sent the SES email.

What did I do wrong?

P.S. Open and click tracking for each app seem to work well independently. I'm not sure why bounces from the first web app are bleeding over into the second.

Comment: How did you catch the bounce event? to trigger SNS. There would be a fault.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I'm trying now (which I think will work) is to have all emails from the second app *also* use a [Configuration Set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-custom-open-click-domains.html#configure-custom-open-click-domain-config-set), pointed to its SNS Topic.

Then at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home?region=us-east-1#verified-senders-domain:, I set “Bounce Notifications SNS Topic” and “Complaint Notifications SNS Topic” to “none”.